# Why would one need to use XMPP for real-time?

Tags: java, xmpp, real-time

I want to make a real-time messaging app. I was just wondering why people use XMPP? What is the advantage of it? Wouldn't be just enough to make URL clients in java to send and receive messages?

Comment: What you mean by "URL client in java"?

Answer (score 2):

To be simple and efficient, create your own protocol, or just use text line for simplification. 
To be extensible and multi-functional, XMPP is a good choice. 
And why should you create a new one if XMPP already satisfied your requirements?

BTW, XMPP is not constrained only for real-time.

Answer (score -4):

"Real-time" is all about be able to predict how much time an operation will take.

XMPP is not a "real-time" communication protocol. XMPP messages are typically routed through multiple hops (like XMPP servers/proxies), which delay messages in an unpredictable way.